# WebApi - HttpRequestMessage RequestUri

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

On the `HttpRequestMessage` I can access a property named `RequestUri`, which gives me a bunch of properties.

However I cannot find one that has what I need. I need to get the path without values assiged.

For example I can get this : **/api/users/1/country/1/city/77/detail**

But what I need is the path without the values : **/api/users/{userId}/country/{countryId}/city/{cityId}/detail**

Is there any way to get it directly?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Route or RoutePrefix? Or are you using regular route mapping?

Comment: @SteenT I'm not sure.. what do you mean? I believe I am using the regular route mapping.

Comment: The default routing in Web Api (version 2 at least) is /api/{controller}/{id}, so you must have configured your routes somewhere, because they're not the default pattern.

Comment: Yes but in this case I am using a DelegatingHandler, so I am not doing that routing configuration here. Does it make a difference on stripping the url without the actual values?